# Fragment + Fragment v4 при вызове replace накладывает друг на друга

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Используются 2 вида фрагментов v4 и обычные (так было очень нужно). Но при replace стало наложение фрагментов друг на друга. Когда все фрагменты были не v4, проблемы не было. Но именно нужно, чтобы были разные. Кто знает в чём проблема?

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
    currentPosition = position;
    Fragment fragment;
    FragmentTransaction ft;
    switch (position) {
        case 1:
            ContactsFragment contactsFragment = new ContactsFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, contactsFragment, contactsFragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                    .addToBackStack(contactsFragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
            break;
        default:
            fragment = new TopFragment();
            ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                    .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Из-за того что используешь SupportFragmentManager и FragmentManager и получается наложение. Поэтому, если хочешь использовать разные виды фрагментов, то придется перед тем, как загружать Fragment вместо Fragment v4, удалять Fragment, и соответственно наоборот, при смене F v4 на F, придется сначала удалить F.

На stackoverflow уже был подобный вопрос - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163631/android-using-both-getfragmentmanager-and-getsupportfragmentmanager-causes-overl